# using the table function in a loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the table() function to run in a for loop, Ideally I would put the output into a dataframe, however I'm not getting below to work, any ideas?

```
for(i in unique(ModuleMarks$Module)){
     table(i[,6])
}
```

Table structure

```
   Module  Out of Mark  Mark percentage Judgment JudgmentChar
   <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>      <chr>    <dbl>        <chr>
1 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test
2 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test
3 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test
4 LW1001            NA    NA       <NA>       NA         test
.
.
.
1 LW6627           100    57         57       57          2.2
2 LW6627           100    63         63       63          2.1
3 LW6627           100    62         62       62          2.1
4 LW6627           100    65         65       65          2.1
5 LW6627           100    67         67       67          2.1
6 LW6627           100    64         64       64          2.1
This goes on for 7000+rows
```

So I'm trying to go though each module code and get the table for each module, which their could be 1 to 500.

The example output would be

```
table(LW1108[,6])
1h  2.1  2.2  3.1 Fail Pass test 
54  196  122   21   23   15    7
```

but for each Module

```
table(LW1108[,6])
Module 1h  2.1  2.2  3.1 Fail Pass test 
LW1101 54  196  122   21   23   15    7 
LW1102 54  196  122   21   23   15    7 
.
.
.
LW6601 54  196  122   21   23   15    7
```

The nub of the problem is that it is not passing i through the table function.

Thanks

Comment: Please, at least show structure of your `ModuleMarks`. Right now `i` in you loop represents not `ModuleMarks` for each `Module` but every `Module` itself.

Comment: you will get `i` time the same table, i think you juste want to  `table(i[,6])` by `somevariable`

Comment: Please specify what you expect as output for your toy data shown

Comment: I'm uisng get to pull out the data, its nearly working            for(i in unique(ModuleMarks$Module)){
  #x = paste(i,"$JudgmentChar",sep="")
  print(i)
  print(table(get(i)[,6]))
  
}

Comment: Hi @pat, please consider accepting an answer (even your own) by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know the answer worked and that the issue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the following...I'll use an example with `mtcars` first

First `split` your data on a column, `cyl`

```
split.mtcars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Then iterate through `split.mtcars` with `map` from `tidyverse`, and make `table` of values in `gear`, convert `table` to `1-row matrix` and then to `data.frame`, rename columns `setNames` as `names` from `table` output. Convert output list from `map` to `data.frame` using `Reduce("full_join"...`. Bind `rownames` as unique values in `cyl`

```
library(tidyverse)
desired <- Reduce("full_join", map(split.mtcars, ~ as.data.frame(matrix(table(.x$gear), nrow=1, byrow=T)) %>% setNames(names(table(.x$gear)))))
rownames(desired) <- names(split.mtcars)
```

Output

```
   3  4 5
4  1  8 2
6  2  4 1
8 12 NA 2
```

#### Same Approach on Your Data

```
split.ModuleMarks <- split(ModuleMarks, ModuleMarks$Module)
desired <- Reduce("full_join", map(split.ModuleMarks, ~ as.data.frame(matrix(table(.x$JudgmentChar), nrow=1, byrow=T)) %>% setNames(names(table(.x$JudgmentChar)))))
rownames(desired) <- names(split.ModuleMarks)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the get() function (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) which pulled out the value for i and changed it to an object, as i was a char it needed to be an object. 
hope this helps

```
#getting the tables of results
for(i in unique(ModuleMarks$Module)){
print(i)
print(table(get(i)[,6]))

}
```